# optional variable declaration in a template

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to declare member variables in a class template if some condition from template parameters is true. I could use nested class as container, but it is impossible to do explicite specializations in that case.

I'm trying someting like this:

```
enum class VarPolice { Declare, DontDeclare };

template<VarPolice vp = VarPolice::Declare>
class MyClass
{
  struct EmptyStruct {};
  struct VarSaverStruct { int MyVar; };

  using VarSaver = typename std::conditional<vp == VarPolice::Declare, VarSaverStruct, EmptyStruct>::type;

  VarSaver saver;
}
```

So, I can use `MyVar` as `saver.MyVar`

Is there any way to do optional variable declaration without using EmptyStruct that has a size overhead?

C++17 can be used.

Comment: c++17 has `std::monostate` which is an empty struct, it's not necessary to declare your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have your cake and eat it too. Just inherit from correct type instead, and rely on the empty base optimization.

```
enum class VarPolice { Declare, DontDeclare };

struct EmptyStruct {};
struct VarSaverStruct { int MyVar; };

template<VarPolice vp = VarPolice::Declare>
class MyClass : std::conditional_t<vp == VarPolice::Declare, 
                                   VarSaverStruct, EmptyStruct>
{
};
```

Standard library implementations rely on it themselves to "store" allocators without taking up space if they are stateless.

Comment: You can also use `std::tuple` to store multiple variables to allow optional compression of empty classes, since I believe every implementation uses EBO (that is not guaranteed, however). If not, Boost has a compressed pair implementation that does just that.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh - I'm not aware of any such guarantees for `std::tuple`. And inheriting from or storing all the classes defeats the purpose of only have the member available when the condition is true.

Comment: There are no guarantees, just every major compiler does this (I believe, I may be wrong about MSVC). Boost has `compressed_pair`, which is also very easy to implement that does just this. It's frequently used in standard library container implementations for allocators (like, libcxx), since inheriting from an allocator is out-of-the-question.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh - Yes, I'm aware. That's the why I added the afterthought at the end.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. Only libc++ and libstdc++ do this. MSVC does not. My bad. Do not use `std::tuple`.

Comment: I can't use MyVar inside the MyClass. It is undeclared for `if constexpr` and using `enable_if_t`. It can be accesed only outside the class (`MyClass c{}; c.MyVar = 5;`)

Comment: @РоманКоптев - Inside templates, name lookup doesn't proceed into base classes, unless it's explicitly made dependent on it, i.e `this->MyVar`. That's just how templates work.